# Can I return a response in a function within a view function?

Tags: python, django, web

Here's the view function:

```
def bar(request):
    ...
    record = get_record_from_model(model, **kwargs)
    ...
    return JsonResponse(data_to_response)
```

and below there is the function used in view function:

```
def get_record_from_model(model, **kwargs):
    try:
        return model.objects.get(**kwargs)
    except model.DoesNotExist:
        error_data = copy.copy(settings.ERROR["NOT_EXIST_ERR"])
        return JsonResponse(error_data)
```

Can I return `JsonResponse(error_data)` to the client in  **get_record_from_model** function when exception occur?

Something like raise **Http404**

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't do it there directly because the calling function still has to do something with the return value from `get_record_for_model`.  That said, I would recommend that you do something like the below, which sends data as well as a found/not found boolean back to the calling function:

```
def get_record_from_model(model, **kwargs):
    try:
        return model.objects.get(**kwargs), True

    except model.DoesNotExist:
        error_data = copy.copy(settings.ERROR["NOT_EXIST_ERR"])
        return error_data, False

...

def bar(request):
    ...
    data, found = get_record_from_model(model, **kwargs)
    if not found:
        return JsonResponse(data, status=404)
    ...
    return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

Comment: data will be used later on and can't just be returned if found, This might not be a good solution.

Comment: I'd rather not use this function...Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use django's built-in shortcut [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def bar(request):
    ...
    record = get_object_or_404(model, **kwargs)
    ...
    return JsonResponse(data_to_response)
```